# node.js : can proxyquire be applied at any level in the call stack?

Tags: node.js, mocking, require, stubbing, proxyquire

Node.js : can proxyquire be be used to mock dependencies at any level in the call stack ?

I need to test route1.endpoint1

route1 requires module1 , which requires module2 , which requires module3

Can I apply proxyquire to module2 -- assigning a stub for its require module3 ?